# Uploading Videos in Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, video, facebook-graph-api

I'm putting together an application in facebook, part of which requires a user to input a bunch of information into a form, including a video and a number of text fields.

For my application, I'm using a combination of HTML, PHP, mySQL and Javascript.

I want to be able to upload the users video file to facebook using the PHP SDK in the same page as I am inserting their info into my database. I want something similiar to the photo solution here: [Exception when uploading photo with Facebook Graph API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3211968/exception-when-uploading-photo-with-facebook-graph-api). But I'm not sure what the array key should be for the video itself.
Can any give me any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

My apologies,

I realized that the solution I linked to works. However, you have to give facebook time to process the video, otherwise the graph api replies false.